# Implement nhibernate. Class + abstract base class

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I have the following database setup:

[image]

I need a nhibernate file that maps it to:

- `PowerPrognosisUsageSubmission` class
- `PowerPrognosisWindSubmission` class
- `PowerPrognosisSubmissionBase` abstract base class

Although, I am getting nowhere. Here is my attempt:

I tried implementing `PowerPrognosisUsageSubmission`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping namespace="DC.Client.Models.Model" assembly="DC.Client.Models" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="PowerPrognosisUsageSubmission" table="PowerPrognosisSubmissionBase" schema="`dbo`" mutable="true" lazy="false">
    <id name="PowerPrognosisSubmissionId" access="property" column="`PowerPrognosisSubmissionBaseID`">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Date" column="`Date`" />
    <property name="Hour" column="`Hour`" />
    <property name="Direction" column="`Direction`" />
    <property name="Submission" column="`Submission`" />
    <property name="Basis" column="`Basis`" />
    <many-to-one name="PowerPrognosisUsageArea" class="PowerPrognosisUsageArea" column="`PowerPrognosisAreaBaseID`" not-null="false" lazy="false" />
    <joined-subclass name="PowerPrognosisUsageSubmission" table="PowerPrognosisUsageSubmission">
      <key column="`Usage`" />
    </joined-subclass>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it on my own

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping namespace="DC.Client.Models.Model" assembly="DC.Client.Models" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="PowerPrognosisSubmissionBase" table="PowerPrognosisSubmissionBase" schema="`dbo`" mutable="true" lazy="false">
    <id name="PowerPrognosisSubmissionId" access="property" column="`PowerPrognosisSubmissionBaseID`">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Date" column="`Date`" />
    <property name="Hour" column="`Hour`" />
    <property name="Direction" column="`Direction`" />
    <property name="Submission" column="`Submission`" />
    <property name="Basis" column="`Basis`" />
    <many-to-one name="PowerPrognosisAreaUsage" class="PowerPrognosisAreaUsage" column="`PowerPrognosisAreaBaseID`" not-null="false" lazy="false" />
    <joined-subclass name="PowerPrognosisSubmissionUsage" table="PowerPrognosisSubmissionUsage">
      <key column="`PowerPrognosisSubmissionBaseID`" />
      <property name="Usage" column="`Usage`" />
    </joined-subclass>
    <joined-subclass name="PowerPrognosisSubmissionWind" table="PowerPrognosisSubmissionWind">
      <key column="`PowerPrognosisSubmissionBaseID`" />
      <property name="PriceAreaEffect" column="`PriceAreaEffect`" />
      <property name="ResponsibleEffect" column="`ResponsibleEffect`" />
      <property name="W2UShare" column="`W2UShare`" />
      <property name="PointCarbonShare" column="`PointCarbonShare`" />
    </joined-subclass>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you take a look at FluentNhibernate, in my opinion, it gives a much better way to mapping tables to your entity classes.

Also, you might wanna give this tool a go, it's capable of generating hbm.xml or fluentnhibernate mapping files for you.

http://nmg.codeplex.com/

Comment: Sorry, I can not change which kind of nhibernate we are using. I'm just a teammember working on a project. I'll try look at the tool

Comment: You could use FluentNHibernate in a separate project and get it to spit out the mappings for you (i.e. cheat ;)

Comment: if you cannot change the mapping types then I strongly suggest you give nhibernate mapping generator a spin. Simply point it to your tables and choose the types of mapping you currently use, it'll automatically generate all xml/mapping classes for you.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you should read the [NHibernate manual](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html). [Chapter 8](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#inheritance) has all the details on inheritance.

Comment: Yes. I was looking at it while making the above example. But as far as I can see, it helps you implement a superclass which inheritances child classes properties. But I want the oppesit. I'll try look again though

Comment: No. I just phrased it bad. What I mean is, that it seems like their examples creates: Payment inherits cheque payments, but I want the oppesit. Using their examples